# Getting android.util.Log to show stacktrace of UnknownHostException

Tags: android, exception, logging, unknown-host

So, Android built in this "feature", that any exception which has an `UnknownHostException` in its *cause* stack will not have its stack trace logged when passed into Log.X methods... See for example the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544539/android-log-x-not-printing-stacktrace) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897239/log-e-does-not-print-the-stack-trace-of-unknownhostexception). Or check [the original commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/dba50c7ed24e05ff349a94b8c4a6d9bb9050973b) which introduced this (n.b. the comment).

Personally I consider this to be a really stupid decision: in my case this so called feature even prevents any kind of `toString()` call on my custom exceptions, so if any error or exception at any point was caused by `UnknownHostException` it'll log just... nothing. :/ (Well yes, I get the timestamp, tag, etc. but no actual logged content.)

- **Is there any way around this issue, except for replacing the logging framework with something else entirely?**

Is there some config I haven't found or some other clever way to fix logging?